# How do I find an apps/websites Deep Link?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have a cordova app which uses the AppAvailability Plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-appavailability) and I have to find out if a specific app is installed. Its easy on Android, since I just know the packagename, but on IOS I have to know the URI Scheme or the DeepLink (eg. myapp://).

But I just seems to not be able to find out how to get it. Example is the asos.com.au website and their app. The Package name is 'com.asos.app', so that part is solved.
But if you go on the website (or in my usecase, if you are forwarding to their website) it opens the app if is available. And if it is available I want to have my app know that it wont redirect to the website (this is actually pretty important).

So, on IOS I have to know this URI Scheme.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Download the app with iTunes, copy/paste the app somewhere else, rename it .zip (and change its behavior), unzip it, navigate until you find a .app, explore it and look for Info.plist.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll try later in the afternoon as soon I'll have a macbook available.

Comment: Larme I tried it, and unfortunately the ASOS app does not implement a custom URI scheme which I could check.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like asos.com has implemented deep linking, and indeed http://www.asos.com/apple-app-site-association is present and looks good. Find more documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: OK, so basically if a website has this file, it should have deeplinking. But in the end I still dont know IF the actual app is installed. Thanks for the link and information tho :)

Comment: I don't think there's a sure-fire way to find out, since custom url schemes are no longer needed to implement this.